# Twitter Pagination

Tags: api, twitter, pagination

I found this Twitter API v2 code sample:

```
 import requests
    import os
    import json
    
    # To set your environment variables in your terminal run the following line:
    # export 'BEARER_TOKEN'='<your_bearer_token>'
    bearer_token = 'XYZ'
```

Method to get URL of user_id

```
def create_url():
    # Replace with user ID below
    user_id = 14699880
    return "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/{}/tweets".format(user_id)
```

Method to fetch params

```
def get_params():
    # Tweet fields are adjustable.
    # Options include:
    # attachments, author_id, context_annotations,
    # conversation_id, created_at, entities, geo, id,
    # in_reply_to_user_id, lang, non_public_metrics, organic_metrics,
    # possibly_sensitive, promoted_metrics, public_metrics, referenced_tweets,
    # source, text, and withheld
    return {"tweet.fields": "created_at"}
```

Method for bearer token authentication

```
def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2UserTweetsPython"
    return r
```

Method for connecting to endpoint

```
 def connect_to_endpoint(url, params):
        response = requests.request("GET", url, auth=bearer_oauth, params=params)
        print(response.status_code)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception(
                "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
                    response.status_code, response.text
                )
            )
        return response.json()
```

Method main to call the functions above

```
def main():
    url = create_url()
    params = get_params()
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url, params)
    print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Problem: I get only 10 results? How can I get more? Does it have to do with 'pagination'?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get tweets using Python.

[image]

You using `Requests` way.

Requests (Twitter [API v2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api)): It can use the requests library in Python to make direct HTTP requests to the Twitter API. Like Tweepy, it'll need Twitter Developer API access and keys(or Bearer Token).

This method provides more control over the API calls but requires manual handling of the request and response.

#### Pagination

Pagination is a feature in Twitter API v2 endpoints that return more results than can be returned in a single response.

`next_token` - String returned within the meta-object response on endpoints that support pagination.

The tweet paging mechanism in the Twitter API allows you to fetch a large number of tweets from a user or search query in a paginated manner. Since the API has rate limits and maximum results per request, paging helps to fetch results beyond these limits by making multiple requests.

The Twitter API v2 uses a cursor-based pagination system. When you make an API request to fetch tweets, you specify the number of tweets per page (up to 100) using the `max_results` parameter. The API response will include a `next_token` in the meta field if there are more tweets available.

[image]

To fetch the next page of results, you need to make another API request with the same parameters as before, but this time includes the `pagination_token` parameter, setting its value to the `next_token` from the previous response.

[image]

More detailed information is here [pagination](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/pagination)

#### Demo

This is demo code

Replace  with your actual Bearer Token
I added `max_results` with 100 in `get_params()` (the default is 10)
It will reduce the number of total API calls.

Save as `get-tweets.py` filename.

```py
import requests
import json
bearer_token = '<your bearer token>'

def create_url():
    # Replace with user ID below
    user_id = 14699880
    return "https://api.twitter.com/2/users/{}/tweets".format(user_id)

def get_params():
    return {
        "max_results": 100,
        "tweet.fields": "created_at"
    }

def bearer_oauth(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"}
    return headers

def connect_to_endpoint(url, params, next_token=None):
    headers = bearer_oauth(bearer_token)

    # next_token subsequent request can be repeated until all (or some number of) Tweets
    if next_token:
        params["pagination_token"] = next_token
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=params)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    return response.json()

def main():
    url = create_url()
    params = get_params()
    next_token = None

    # keep getting Tweet until next_token is None
    while True:    
        json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url, params, next_token)
        print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        # assign next_token from response
        if 'meta' in json_response and 'next_token' in json_response['meta']:
            next_token = json_response['meta']['next_token']
        else:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Run it

```
python get-tweets.py
```

#### Result

[image]